# Bind dropdown using jQuery in ruby on rails.syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ':' render :text => [@storeitem.unit_pr... ^

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controller Indent and InventoryStoreItem relation is 'indent-'has_many :inventory_store_items' and inventory_store_item-'belongs_to :indent'.when i select drop down as store_item_id(i.e is item_name) from indent-form it will fetch store item attributes i.e is unit_price,quantity,batch_no from store item. I tried using  when user select drop down option from select box. than on change event will fire and through ajax.but the js did'nt works.This is my code.

## indent_controller

```
class IndentsController < ApplicationController
def index_indent 
 @store_items = InventoryStoreItem.find(params[:id])
 @indents = Indent.all
 @stores = InventoryStore.all
end

def load_item_data
 @storeitem = InventoryStoreItem.find_by_id(params[:inventory_store_item_id]).present? InventoryStoreItem.find(params[:inventory_store_item_id]): InventoryStoreItem.unscoped.find_by_id(params[:inventory_store_item_id])
end
```

## indent.js.coffee

```
 #Load Items data when an item is selected from dropdown list
'$('#select_inventory_store_item_id').on('change',function(){ var inventory_store_item_id = $('#select_inventory_store_item_id').val() $.ajax({ url: '/indents/load_item_data', type: 'GET', data: {'id' : inventory_store_item_id}, dataType: 'json' }).success(function(data) })'
```

## new_indent

```
<%= form_for @indent, url:{controller: 'indents',action:'create_indent'} do |c|%>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Indent No:</b></div>
   <%=c.text_field :indent_no, placeholder: "Indent No", class: "form-control",style:"width:250px"%>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Expected Date:</b></div>
   <%= c.date_field :expected_date, :value => Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),class: "datepicker form-control",style:"width:250px" %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Description</b></div>
   <%=c.text_field :description, class: "form-control",style: 'width:350px;height:100px'%>
 </div>

 <h3>Indent Items</h3>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Required</b></div>
   <%=c.text_field :required, placeholder: "Required", class: "form-control",style:"width:250px"%>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Pending</b></div>
   <%=c.text_field :pending, placeholder: "Pending", class: "form-control",style:"width:250px"%>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"> <b>Store Item:</b></div>
   <td class="col-3"> <%= c.select :inventory_store_item_id,InventoryStoreItem.all.collect{|b| [b.item_name,b.id]},{prompt:"select Item"}%></td>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Unit_price</b></div>
   <%=text_field_tag :unit_price%>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Quantity</b></div>
   <%=text_field_tag :quantity%>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-3"><b>Batch No</b></div>
   <%=text_field_tag :batch_no%>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4"> 
  <div class="form-actions">               
   <%= c.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-primary"%>
 </div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [render :json](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render). It will be better to use it instead of `:text` if you are using ajax.

Comment: @DiodonHystrix I tried as u stated above but want i want is how will i get single store item id when i select drop down option. As if now it dispalying all store items in index_indent page. what should i write in this index_indent method:                                     `def index_indent 
 @store_items = InventoryStoreItem.find(params[:id]) <--how it will display single item by this line.If I wrote @store_items = InventoryStoreItem.all it displays all store items.
 @indents = Indent.all
 @stores = InventoryStore.all
end`

Answer (score 0):

`data: {id: inventory_store_item_id}` 
It should be `data: {inventory_store_item_id: inventory_store_item_id}`.

Your `load_item_data` action is still wrong. The syntax is `condition ? true : false`.

`@storeitem = InventoryStoreItem.find_by_id(params[:inventory_store_item_id]).present? ? InventoryStoreItem.find(params[:inventory_store_item_id]) : InventoryStoreItem.unscoped.find_by_id(params[:inventory_store_item_id])`

Comment: @DiodonHystrixThanks for the quick reply. When i select drop down option how the fields will automatically fill up by unit_price, quantity n batch_no. and i have updated my new_indent form.

Comment: You should probably do it in the ajax, here: `success(function(data) })'`